# Conda UnsatisfiableError of glibc when trying to install Comet ML 3.18 in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, glibc, anaconda3, comet-ml

I'm trying to install Comet ML version `3.18` in a Dockerfile using Anaconda but the build fails with the following error:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - python=3.8 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

Isn't my installed version exactly what is needed according to these lines?! I've googled this issue over and over again but couldn't find a solution that's why I'm now asking it here. Sorry if this is a duplicate but it's driving me nuts! (Had a similar issue trying to install Comet ML on the cluster directly using Anaconda - without Docker - and there the error was with `glibc 2.17`.)

Any help is appreciated!

---

Here's the **full Dockerfile**:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest

RUN conda install -c comet_ml comet_ml=3.18 -y

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

I also have a version where I install Anaconda manually in Ubuntu 20.04 but it throws the same error and I thought a more concise Dockerfile would be nicer.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?  I am seeing a similar error with ```pygraphviz```:```pygraphviz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']```, but then ```Your installed version is: 2.17```.